# Axios catch crashes code, marked "UnhandledPromiseRejection"

Tags: node.js, axios, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

I am trying to handle an axios call failure.
I wrote the function and the code:

```
async function createFunction (url, APIKEY, vendorType) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'post',
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: `${url}/vendors/packages`,
      headers: { 
        'x-api-key': `${APIKEY}`
      },
      timeout: 10000,
      data: {
        "contentType": vendorType,
      }
    };
    axios.request(options)
    .then(response =>{
      if (response.status && response.status == 200) {
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        reject(`createFunction Axios call failed with status ${response.status}: ${response.data}`)
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(`createFunction Axios call failed: ${err}`);
    })
  });
}

KbartFunctions.createPackage(host,APIKEY,vendortype)
.then((response) => {
console.log(response);
})
```

I am getting an error:

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "createFunction Axios call failed: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

I thought I handled the rejection correctly, but the code crashes anyway.
Because the error reads "createFunction Axios call failed:" I know it's in the Catch segment and not the then segment (otherwise it would have said "createFunction Axios call failed with status").

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `catch` call right after `then` on `KbartFunctions`

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

- Missing `catch` method call in the calling code: `KbartFunctions.createPackage(...)`
- Unnecessary use of the `Promise` constructor, which is an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

`axios.request` already returns a promise, so no need to create a new promise yourself using the `Promise` constructor. You can just return the promise returned by `axios.request(...)`.

Your code can be simplified as below:

```js
function createFunction(url, APIKEY, vendorType) {
  const options = {
    ...
  };

  return axios
    .request(options)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status && response.status == 200) {
        return response;
      } else {
        throw new Error(
          `createFunction Axios call failed with status ${response.status}:${response.data}`
        );
      }
    });
}

KbartFunctions.createPackage(host, APIKEY, vendortype)
 .then(response => {
   console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(error => { /* handle the error */ });
```

Couple of points to note in the rafactored code:

- The `catch` method call has been removed inside the `createFunction` function. This is because if you just throw the error caught in the `catch` method callback, you can just omit the `catch` method call and allow the calling code to catch and handle the error.
- You had marked `createFunction` as an `async` function but didn't use the `async-await` syntax. Instead you used promise chaining. So, I removed the `async` keyword from the function signature.

If you want to rewrite the `createFunction` using the `async-await` syntax, it can be done as shown below:

```js
async function createFunction(url, APIKEY, vendorType) {
  const options = {
    ...
  };

  const response = await axios.request(options);

  if (response.status && response.status == 200) {
    return response;
  } else {
    throw new Error(
      `createFunction Axios call failed with status ${response.status}: ${response.data}`
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very detailed!
I am still learning node js and all these promises give me a headache